# Swift 3 cannot converted argument of type .. to expected argument type "inout _"

Tags: swift, swift3

It just converted my small Swift project to Swift 3.

Here is a compiler error that I don't understand:

```
var onLoadedClosures: [() -> ()] = []
open func onLoaded(closure: () -> ()) {
    onLoadedClosures += [closure]
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type '[() -> ()]' to expected argument type 'inout _'.

I added the inout keyword:

```
    open func onLoaded(closure: inout () -> ()) {
        onLoadedClosures += [closure]
    }
```

Then it works. But why does adding an element to an array require the inout keyword? Although I know what inout means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a confusing error message – the problem is that you need to mark your `closure:` parameter as `@escaping` in order to allow it to escape the lifetime of the function `onLoaded(closure:)` (as per [SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md), closure function arguments are now non-escaping by default).

```
var onLoadedClosures: [() -> ()] = []
open func onLoaded(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    onLoadedClosures += [closure]
}
```

The reason it works when you mark the parameter as `inout` is because `inout` closures are escaping by definition (as their value get written back to the caller upon the function exiting). However in this case there is simply no need for an `inout` parameter.

For more information about `@escaping`, see [the Swift evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) on the change, as well as [this relevant Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38990882/2976878).